# Retrieving Digits into an Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, input

I am doing a JavaScript, trying to retrieve the user's numerical input, and store the input's digits as an array.

I managed to retrieve the user's input using DOM, but, how can I store the digits into an array?

Comment: Why not post the code you have, and an example of what output you want ?

Comment: Either input.split() or input.split(",") depending on what your input is

Answer (score 2):

If you want to obtain an array of **numbers**, one solution is to use `Array.from` method and `map` array items to numbers.

```js
let number=1234;
let array=Array.from(number.toString()).map(Number);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store singular digits, you could use .split('')

```js
userInput = '42';

console.log(userInput.split(''));
```

Comment: userInput is not defined

Answer (score 1):

what you can do here is simply:

```
userInput1 = '42';
userInput2 = '43';
const inputArray = [userInput1, userInput2]
```

Comment: userInput is not defined

Answer (score 0):

For an array of number:

```js
var input = "123456789";
var array = input.split('')
for(var i = 0; i <array.length; i++) { array[i] = +array[i]; } 
console.log(array)
```

The operation `+array[i]` is just a quick way to do the number conversion.

If you want the array of chars remove the `for loop` from the code